# Hybris Impex create a script for Product import

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I've tried searching for examples, but all of them produce problems for me. Here's the easiest one, which looks like it's supposed to work

```
$lang=en

$productCatalog=productCatalog
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$productCatalog]),version[default='Staged'])[unique=true,default=$productCatalog:Staged]     

INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];catalogVersion ;M300047;$productCatalog:Staged
```

I'm new to Hybris, especially Hybris Impex and am kinda stuck at this point, so I'd appreciate your help for sure.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions so you will be better prepared and able to ask a question that will be well received and more importantly **answerable**. This is not a *send me teh codez* site, that is now how this site works.

Answer (score -1):

Seems the syntax is wrong on the header of the INSERT_UPDATE. You are missing a **$** in the catalogVersion attribute. Also, usually, catalogVersion is also used as a unique attribute, so you don't duplicate codes inside the same catalog. It should be like this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];$catalogVersion[unique=true]
```

You can also find more examples and explanations [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/14/what-is-impex-syntax-of-impex-different-modes-of-impex-and-import-via-impex-web/) if you don't have access to help.hybris.com yet.